# How to apply date filter in firestore

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

I have many documents in a firestore collection, I want to apply a date/timestamp filter on `created_at` field. My database timestamp format is Unix Timestamp(e.g.1593694213.294639). I'm using this `2020-8-1` date format in `where()` during query.

[image]

I tried the followings code to apply the date filter:

```
db.collection('my_collection')
    .where('created_at', '>=', new Date('2020-8-1'))
    .get()
    .then((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            console.log(doc.data());
        });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
    });
```

But this code throwing an error.

> Error getting documents:  Error: 9 FAILED_PRECONDITION: The query requires an index.

How can I filter this field?

Comment: "*But this code throwing an error*" - your question should clearly state what the error is and which line of code generated it.

Comment: Throwing this error: Error getting documents:  Error: 9 FAILED_PRECONDITION: The query requires an index.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing#create_a_missing_index_through_an_error_message):

*If you attempt a [compound query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries) with a range clause that doesn't map to an existing index, you receive an error. The error message includes a direct link to create the missing index in the Firebase console.*

You can refer to the above documentation to find the steps about creating an index for your `>=` range clause.